# Can a complication ever appear larger than, or outside of, its designated container?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-complication

I've written a watchface that also acts as a data provider. When I add my face's complication to another watch face, if the user taps on the complication I would like to (briefly) show a full screen of information, and then return to the original watchface.

I've been able to mostly accomplish this, except the information appears only within the space of the complication itself. Is there a way to have it appear fullscreen (that is, overlaying the original face)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the [ComplicationData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/complications/ComplicationData.html) object in your data provider you can register a tap action using [setTapAction](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/complications/ComplicationData.Builder.html#setTapAction(android.app.PendingIntent)) (on the Builder). Use a PendingIntent that launches an activity in your application. This activity can take up the entire screen. When it is dismissed, after a timeout or user action, the watch face will be displayed again.

Comment: Thank you, TofferJ, that was exactly the right answer. A new intent/activity works perfectly!